# Can node-pg-migrate target a specific schema?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-pg-migrate

I have a node.js project which uses node-pg-migrate to manage the database in the public schema.

I have a second project, and want to use node-pg-migrate to manage an additional schema within the same database.

Is it possible to target node-pg-migrate for the second project for a specific schema, with its own pgmigrations table (that's independent of the first project, which already has pgmigrations in the public schema)?

Basically I want to separate the projects and have them manage their own independent migrations in different schemas

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me:

```
npx node-pg-migrate up -s schema_name
```